# Trying to make a number averaging program that will terminate the program and show the average when '-1' is inputted into the system

Tags: java, input, average, calculator

I've been trying to get a hang of this number averaging program, basically, it takes inputs from the user, and once -1 is inputted, it will average all those inputs. I'm struggling to find a way to give the average as it is giving strange answers as of yet.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopingDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "";
        int num = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int z = -1;
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        counter++;

        while (i <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please input a number");
            input = in.nextLine();

            num = Integer.parseInt(input);

            if (num == z) {
                int average = sum / counter;
                System.out.println("Average value is: " + average);
            } else {
                sum += num;
            }

            //what does this operator do? sum = sum + num
        }

        counter++;
    }
}
```

I do apologize in advance if this is breaking any rules.

Comment: you are doing integer division, changes the variables to doubles

Comment: One of your questions is hidden in the source code. Yes `sum += num` is a shorthand for `sum = sum + num`. As for the rest: please create a  [MCVE] and give concrete expected and observed values.

Comment: Define your inputs, and define your "strange answers". What are they. Why are they strange?

Comment: "Strange answers" that you get are totals, not averages, because you increment `count` outside the loop, and because you do integer division.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was about to say almost the same thing then noticed your answer. I would like to point out, however, that "integer division" is not a problem, it simply rounds the result, rather than returning a decimal and should not hinder the given results enough to matter.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int counter = 1;
while (true) {

    System.out.println("Please input a number");
    input = in.nextLine();

    num = Integer.parseInt(input);

    if (num == z) {
        double average = (double)sum / counter;
        System.out.println("Average value is: " + average);
        break;
    } else {
        sum += num;
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code-only answer are discouraged. You should explain the problem(s), as well as the changes you made and how they fix the problem(s).